# Is the non-directive a legal c preprocesing directive?

Tags: c, compilation, c-preprocessor, c99

[The c99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says almost nothing about the non-directive - only that it's "a directive", in the sense of being illegal to place in a macro argument list (footnote 150, attached to 6.10.3p11).

One would assume this lack of definition means that any non-directive causes undefined behavior, and should be reported as an error, and this is mostly the case with both gcc and clang.

However, in both compilers, the line:

```c
# 123 "filename"
```

is equivalent to:

```c
# line 123 "filename"
```

even when the `-std=c99` flag is set.

Why is that the case? I've only found [a single mention of it online](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1740.htm), without a resolution.

Comment: Re “should be reported as an error”: Undefined behavior, more properly called behavior not defined by the C standard, is not necessarily an error. The C standard is not intended to define a complete language that has the same behavior on all platforms. It is, among other purposes, designed to provide a core language that can be used flexibly in various environments. It provides a base language that can be extended. Compilers may fill in the blanks of “undefined behavior” with their own extensions, as by defining their own directives. These are not errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C 2018 6.10 9 says:

> The execution of a non-directive preprocessing directive results in undefined behavior.

So, yes, it is “legal” (the C standard does not prohibit you from including it in your program or prohibit a C implementation from defining the behavior), but its behavior is not defined by the C standard.

This paragraph is not present in the C 1999 standard, but then the behavior is still undefined by omission (C 1999 4 2: “… Undefined behavior is otherwise indicated in this International Standard by the words “undefined behavior” or by the omission of any explicit definition of behavior…”).

Answer (score 2):

Using `-std=c99` does not automatically reject anything not specified with the C99 standard. If you want that, also add `-pedantic`. That generates a warning for the line.

```
k.c:1:3: warning: style of line directive is a GCC extension
    1 | # 123 "filename"
      |   ^~~
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

> -pedantic
>
> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++. For ISO C, follows the version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used.

However, do note this:

> Some users try to use -pedantic to check programs for strict ISO C conformance. They soon find that it does not do quite what they want: it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all---only those for which ISO C requires a diagnostic, and some others for which diagnostics have been added.
>
> A feature to report any failure to conform to ISO C might be useful in some instances, but would require considerable additional work and would be quite different from -pedantic. We don't have plans to support such a feature in the near future.